# How to run multiple docker compose files at once

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are 13 dockerized microservices in a project and I need to have one `docker-compose.yml` file to run all the `docker-compose.yml` files of every project. From what I googled, I found using a `.env` seems to be the best practice. So this is what I do: Let's have two docker-compose files, `Project1.yml` and `Project2.yml` as follows

**project1.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  hello_world_a:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: hw_a

  hello_world_b:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: hw_b
```

**project2.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  hello_world_2:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: hw_2
```

I created a `docker-compose.yml` file as follows

```
version: '3'
services:
  apps:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: hw_c
    env_file:
      - .env
```

with the following `.env` file

**.env File**

```
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:
COMPOSE_FILE=project1.yaml:docker-compose.yaml:project2.yaml
```

and inside the directory where `docker-compose.yml` resides, I run `docker compose up -d` and I get the following running containers

[image]

**However, I need the `docker-compose.yml` to be only a gateway to run other docker-compose files and I do not want this file to have any services. How can I do this?**

## update 1

To create an empty container I used `scratch` image as follows

```
version: '3'
services:
  apps:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    container_name: apps
    env_file:
      - .env
```

and this is the `DockerFile`

```
FROM scratch
```

But I get an error

> Error response from daemon: No command specified

## update 2

Finally I changed the `.env` as follows and it worked

```
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:
COMPOSE_FILE=project1.yaml:project2.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the setup you're showing, setting the [`COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_file) is the important thing.  The `.env` file must be in the current directory, but if you explicitly set `COMPOSE_FILE`, you do not specifically need a `docker-compose.yml` file in the directory as well.

The last `.env` file in the question is enough; you do not need a Compose file with a dummy container:

```sh
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:
COMPOSE_FILE=project1.yaml:project2.yaml
```

With this setup, the `.env` file contains control variables specific to Compose, and you do not need to pass it on to individual containers using `env_file:` directives.  I also might avoid explicitly setting `container_name:` to avoid potential conflicts.  For larger projects there are also possible conflicts around manually-assigned `ports:`.

Depending on your networking needs, I also might consider the merits of just starting all of the Compose projects separately.  This will mean that each project's containers have an automatically-assigned name prefix and you don't need to specifically name the project in the container names.  You may need to configure each service's `default` network to point at a shared network with a known name.

```yaml
# project1/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  a:
    image: redis:latest
    # ports: ['6379']  # if required; to find the host port
    #                  # `docker-compose port a 6379`
    # no container_name: or env_file:
networks:
  default:
    name: project
    external: true
```

```sh
docker network create project
for d in project*; do
  (cd "$d" && docker-compose up -d)
done
```

Comment: The setup I showed in the question also runs each container separately, every project has its own `docker-compose.yaml` file. What is the difference between my solution and the `for` loop you suggested?

Comment: The `port` is also a challenge to me. Letting the docker choose an ephemeral port is a solution, however, it creates its own problems. Do you suggest listing the ports for every container of all the 13 microservices in the .env file and letting the `docker-compose` file use those variables?

Comment: Compose has the notion of a "project", which implies some namespacing.  So there's a difference here between needing unique per-service names across 13 projects, and letting Compose create a unique name for you.  There's also a difference between having 13 separate networks and a single shared network.

Comment: Publishing ports is always going to be a challenge with the constraints you note.  You can get some mileage out of not publishing ports for internal components like databases.  If you have a top-level reverse proxy, you might not need to publish any ports aside from that proxy.

Comment: I encountered another problem asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071317/docker-docker-compose-of-nginx-mounts-the-volume-in-wrong-directory. Can you help me with that?\

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed the .env as follows and it worked

```
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:
COMPOSE_FILE=project1.yaml:project2.yaml
```

You can also remove the `DockerFile` and simply write

```
version: '3'
services:
  apps:
    image: scratch
    container_name: apps
    env_file:
      - .env
```