# Docker: docker-compose of Nginx mounts the volume in wrong directory

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

There are 13 microservices in a project, I created a `.env` file to run all `docker-compose` files by one command. What I did is given in [How to run multiple docker-compose files at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042471/how-to-run-multiple-docker-compose-files-at-once). Briefly, this is directory structure

```
.env
core-service
 |  dockerfiles
    | nginx
sale-service
 |  dockerfiles
    | nginx
```

and this is the `.env` file at a root directory which contains `core-service` and `sale-service`.

```
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:
COMPOSE_FILE=./core-service/docker-compose.yml:./sale-service/docker-compose.yml

CORE_PHP_PORT=9001
CORE_NGINX_PORT=8001
CORE_MYSQL_PORT=3307
CORE_MYSQL_USERNAME="username"
CORE_MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
CORE_MYSQL_DATABASE="database"

SALE_PHP_PORT=9002
SALE_NGINX_PORT=8002
SALE_MYSQL_PORT=3308
SALE_MYSQL_USERNAME="username"
SALE_MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
SALE_MYSQL_DATABASE="database"
```

The `docker-compose` of `sale-service` is this

```
version: '3'
networks:
  sale_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  sale_php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    container_name: "sale_php"
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - sale_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${SALE_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  sale_nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: sale_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${SALE_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - sale_network      
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./dockerfiles/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./dockerfiles/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - sale_php
  sale_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: sale_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${SALE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${SALE_MYSQL_USERNAME:-root}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${SALE_MYSQL_PASSWORD:-secret}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${SALE_MYSQL_PASSWORD:-secret}
      SERVICE_TAGS: sale
    networks:
      - sale_network
    
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

and this is the `dockerfiles/nginx/default.conf` of `sale-service`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    client_max_body_size 64M;
  
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

 

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass sale_php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
      
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

However, the `sale_nginx` gets no port and keeps restarting. The log file of this container gives the following error

> host not found in upstream "core_php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:25

The `core_php` is the PHP service of `core-service`. I suspect that it loads the dockerfiles in `core-service` directory, since it is the first one in `.env`.

When I run `docker compose up -d` inside the `sale-service`  directory every thing is OK, but when I run from the directory that contains `.env` file (to load all compose files) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Docker documentation, [Merge Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/) contains this warning:

> ... all paths in the files are relative to the base Compose file (the first Compose file specified with `-f`).

The [Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/03-compose-file/) part of the "specification" file format also clarifies:

> Relative paths are resolved based on the first Compose file's parent folder, whenever complimentary files being merged are hosted in other folders.

This seems like it is a critical problem for the combined-application approach you're trying to use here.  Both the relative paths in `volumes:` and in `build:` will be interpreted relative to the location of the first Compose file, which will interfere with being able to run each project independently.

The best workaround that comes to mind is to remove all of the `volumes:` that refer to host directories, instead `COPY`ing content into the containers' respective images.  (For example, create a `FROM nginx` container that `COPY`s the static assets and config files into the image.)  You'd then need to manually set the `image:` name for each, and separately `docker-compose build` each project before you `docker-compose up` the combined project.  That seems strictly harder than just `docker-compose up` all of the subprojects independently.

Comment: I set the absolute path to `.env` file and let the `docker-compose` to read from it. Is this a good practice?