# Docker compose from different directories doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

There are 13 microservices named `MS1, ..., MS13`. According to the technique given in [How to run multiple docker-compose files at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042471/how-to-run-multiple-docker-compose-files-at-once), I created one `.env` file at the root direcroty of microservices, say `/var/www/html`, each microservice has its own `docker-compose.yml` when I run the following command from root path `/var/www/html`

> docker compose up -d

every docker-compose file is successfully running and all containers and images are created. However, when I run the command

> docker compose down

inside a microservice, it doesn't stop the services corresponding to the current microservice, and it only works when the current directory is the root directory `/var/www/html` which stops everything.

**How can I fix this? I need to stop services of a microservice from its directory by one `docker compose down` command**

Here is an example of a `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
  psychology_network:
    name: psychology_network
    driver: bridge

services:
  psychology_php:
    build:
      context: ${PSYCHOLOGY_DIRECTORY}
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    image: psychology_php
    container_name: "psychology_php"
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - psychology_network
    volumes:
      - ${PSYCHOLOGY_DIRECTORY}:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${PSYCHOLOGY_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  psychology_nginx:
    build:
      context: ${PSYCHOLOGY_DIRECTORY}
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile         
    image: psychology_nginx
    container_name: psychology_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${PSYCHOLOGY_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - psychology_network    
      - common_network  
    volumes:
      - ${PSYCHOLOGY_DIRECTORY}:/var/www/html      
    depends_on:
      - psychology_php
  psychology_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: psychology_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${PSYCHOLOGY_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${PSYCHOLOGY_MYSQL_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${PSYCHOLOGY_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PSYCHOLOGY_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: psychology
    networks:
      - psychology_network
    
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

As you see, the `nginx` and `php` have the directive `image`, It makes me sure that the image created by running `docker compose up -d` from every directory doesn't affect the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `docker compose` in a directory it infers a project name from the directory that is used as a prefix on all docker objects it creates as well as attached as a label (`com.docker.compose.namespace`) to any created objects that supports labels.

This project namespace is how docker compose determines which objects are in scope. It doesn't really care about the folder its being run in.
This means if you want a single `docker compose down` to remove all microservices they all need to be deployed to the same docker compose project.

This can be done either

- by passing an explicit `--project-name` directive on each call to `docker compose`
- by setting the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable
- by adding a `name:` directive to each `compose.yml` file.

Documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_project_name)

--

PS.  Support for include directives has been added to docker compose recently which, combined with other features like `profiles` should make this kind of project much easier to deal with as a single compose project.

Comment: Your solution has a problem with networks. I followed the third solution and received this warning `a network with name user_network exists but was not created for project "user". Set `external: true` to use an existing network`

Comment: I'd start by inspecting the `user_network`. If its a project local network it should indicate such in its labels.